# usb boot Pop OS on Thinkpad E15 g2 not possible

Tags: boot, bios, pop-os

**General** 
A few weeks ago I created a bootable usb flash drive with Pop OS on it. After that I tested it on my Thinkpad E585 and it worked just fine (even very fast since I used a 450 mbs/s usb drive). Since I loved Pop OS compared to Windows 10 so much I wanted to try it out on my brandnew Thinkpad E15 g2. Unfortunately, it doesn't boot from the usb drive.

**What I've tried**

1. Changing the boot priority order, so that the Windows boot manager was at the bottom and the PC should check to usb ports first.
2. Trying out wether the usb flash drive still works (yes, it did)
3. Disable secure boot (see Problem 2)
4. switch from UEFI first to legacy first (see Problem 1)

**Problems**

1. No option the change from UEFI to legacy ([see the lenovo announcement](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht510878-legacy-bios-boot-support-removed-in-lenovo-2020-products))
2. After disableing the secure boot, a [weird window of BitLocker](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitlocker%20recovery%20key%20lenovo&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE925DE925&sxsrf=ALeKk00R1IR8XpVV5kgyphCvgypQy9wgCw:1605689771878&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidjePD3IvtAhUD2uAKHd5xBPUQ_AUoAXoECBQQAw&biw=1536&bih=722#imgrc=PtS5yVdhz0YeOM) shows up

**Questions**

1. Is there a list with all the compatible devices for Pop OS? I can't find one
2. Is it possible to boot Pop OS from UEFI?
3. Would a downgrade of my BIOS version help? (in order to have the UEFI or legacy option)
4. If it is impossible to boot Pop OS from usb, can I just make a dual boot (Windows 10 and Pop OS) and Pop OS will work?
5. Are there other Linux distros out there which can boot without legacy?

Comment: You really do not want legacy. I do not know Pop!OS, but thought it used SystemD boot which is a UEFI boot loader. But UEFI only boots external drives from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. So did Pop install boot loader to internal ESP, not an ESP on USB drive? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair